# media-queris проблема с низкими разрешениями

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Проблема пустяковая, но всё же очень тормозит процесс. Дело в том, что media-queris на разрешениях экрана до 500px сразу применяются, а media-queris на 320px очень долго или вообще не применяется. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: я пошарился и выяснил, что разрешение просто не применяется, а применяется то, которое было предыдущее

Comment: думаете. без примера кода всё тут же бросятся строить догадки? )

Comment: media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {#test{color:red;}}    media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {#test{color:green;}} По идее при разрешении 300px цвет #test должен быть красным, но он зелёный

Comment: Поменяйте запросы местами. Так как второй запрос шире до 700px, то сначала надо указывать его. А потом более узкий до 576px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз вы хотите, чтобы при меньшем значении ширины окна у вас менялись стили, то медиа-запросы следует указывать в порядке уменьшения ширины. Как-нибудь так:

```
media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #test {
    color: green;
  }
}

media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  #test {
    color: red;
  }
}
```